# Parsing file based on column ID: perl

Tags: perl, parsing, hash, multiple-columns, subroutine

I have a tab delineated file with repeated values in the first column. The single, but repeated values in the first column correspond to multiple values in the second column. It looks something like this:

```
    AAAAAAAAAA1     m081216|101|123
    AAAAAAAAAA1     m081216|100|1987
    AAAAAAAAAA1     m081216|927|463729
    BBBBBBBBBB2     m081216|254|260489
    BBBBBBBBBB2     m081216|475|1234
    BBBBBBBBBB2     m081216|987|240
    CCCCCCCCCC3     m081216|433|1000
    CCCCCCCCCC3     m081216|902|366 
    CCCCCCCCCC3     m081216|724|193
```

For every type of sequence in the first column, I am trying to print to a file with just the sequences that correspond to it. The name of the file should include the repeated sequence in the first column and the number of sequences that correspond to it in the second column. In the above example I would therefore have 3 files of 3 sequences each. The first file would be named something like "AAAAAAAAAA1.3.txt" and look like the following when opened:

```
    m081216|101|123
    m081216|100|1987
    m081216|927|463729
```

I have seen other similar questions, but they have been answered with using a hash. I don't think I can't use a hash because I need to keep the number of relationships between columns. Maybe there is a way to use a hash of hashes? I am not sure. 
Here is my code so far.

```
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use List::MoreUtils 'true';

    open(IN, "<", "/path/to/in_file") or die $!;

    my @array;
    my $queryID;

    while(<IN>){
            chomp;
            my $OutputLine = $_;
            processOutputLine($OutputLine);
    }


    sub processOutputLine {
            my ($OutputLine) = @_;
            my @Columns = split("\t", $OutputLine);
            my ($queryID, $target) = @Columns;
            push(@array, $target, "\n") unless grep{$queryID eq $_} @array;
            my $delineator = "\n";
            my $count = true { /$delineator/g } @array;
            open(OUT, ">", "/path/to/out_$..$queryID.$count.txt") or die $!;
            foreach(@array){
                    print OUT @array;
            }
     }
```

Comment: You'll probably also want to remove the file write from the loop, or you'll be writing over it with every line of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would still recommend a hash. However, you store all sequences related to the same id in an anonymous array which is the value for that ID key. It's really two lines of code.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $filename = 'rep_seqs.txt';   # input file name
open my $in_fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

my %seqs;
foreach my $line (<$in_fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($id, $seq) = split /\t/, $line;
    push @{$seqs{$id}}, $seq;
}
close $in_fh;

my $out_fh;
for (sort keys %seqs) {
    my $outfile = $_ . '_' . scalar @{$seqs{$_}} . '.txt';
    open $out_fh, '>', $outfile  or do {
        warn "Can't open $outfile: $!";
        next;
    };
    say $out_fh $_ for @{$seqs{$_}};
}
close $out_fh;
```

With your input I get the desired files, named `AA..._count.txt`, with their corresponding three lines each.  If items separated by `|` should be split you can do that while writing it out, for example.

Comments

- The anonymous array for a key `$seqs{$id}` is created once we `push`, if not there already
- If there are issues with tabs (converted to spaces?), use `' '`. See the comment.
- A filehandle is closed and re-opened on every `open`, so no need to close every time

---

The default pattern for `split` is  `' '`, also triggering specific behavior -- it matches "*any contiguous whitespace*", and also omits leading whitespace. (The pattern `/ /` matches a single space, turning off this special behavior of `' '`.) See a more precise description on the [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) page. Thus it is advisable to use `' '` when splitting on unspecified number of spaces, since in the case of `split` this is a bit idiomatic, is perhaps the most common use, and is its default.  Thanks to [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) for prompting this comment and update (the original post had the equivalent `/\s+/`).

Note that in this case, since `' '` is the default along with `$_`, we can shorten it a little

```
for (<$in_fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id, $seq) = split;
    push @{$seqs{$id}}, $seq;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and insightful comments. I noticed that in your response, "close $fh_in;" should be really "close $in_fh;". Also, regarding the second half of my question, do you have any tricks on how to append the name of each file with the number of sequences contained within that specific file? Thanks again for your tremendous help!!!

Comment: @Rob Thank you for these comments!  I like to label filehandles as `$specs_fh` -- will correct.  And, I forgot about your requirement to add the count to name, will add that now.  Thank you for the attribution.

Comment: @Rob  I added the count  to the filename. The `scalar` returns the length of a list (number of elements), and array references can be used as lists by dereferencing, `@{ array_ref }`, so it's really simple. I separate the count in the filename by `_`, if you actually wish `.` please change `'_'` to `'.'`.

Comment: It is very exciting to have this code done! Not only done, but done well and quickly. Thank you so much @zdim.

Comment: @Rob Oh, thank you, that's very nice to hear.  I am glad it works for you :)  Please let me know if any other clarifications or comments or such can be useful.

Comment: *"If there are issues with tabs (converted to spaces?), use `/\s+/`"* `split /\s+/` should almost always be `split ' '`, which is the default.

Comment: @Borodin  Thank you,sure. Changed, with a comment. I still like to emphasize that it is multiple spaces by using `\s+`.  But you are right, I should drop that -- in case of `split` the  `' '` is clearer.